# Dump [bezier] in the brazier?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

[bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier) seems to be more popular (471 questions tagged) than his curves (380 questions tagged [bezier-curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier-curve)). The former has no Wiki while the latter does.

[bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier) by itself seems quite ambiguous; does it mean bezier curves, for which there's already a tag, or does it mean bezier surfaces or bezier splines?

If it's about Pierre Bézier himself then such questions are surely off-topic and should be closed!

Should we retag questions with [bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier) to [bezier-curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier-curve)? Or like the comment suggests, make it a synonym of the obvious?

Comment: I'd suggest doing a synonym instead of a retag, otherwise the next person with 1500 rep that has a question about it will create it again.

Comment: I agree. Given the number of questions with this tag, perhaps making it a synonym is better.

Comment: Haha this pun, my favorite!! :DD

Comment: But the pun relies on an incorrect pronunciation... though admittedly I'm not sure there are any English words that rhyme with "[Bézier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Bézier)".

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: Lazy day. Hazy way. Crazy pay. Lemme say. If you can think of a single word though, I'll be impressed.

Comment: I like how this is both a [tag:synonym-request] _and_ a [tag:burninate-request] (and a [tag:retag-request], just for good measure.)

Comment: @reirab Thanks for pointing this out. I removed the burninate request but retained the other two though, since it was originally intended to be a discussion on deciding between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are roughly 26 questions that aren't clearly about the usual curves](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbezier%5D+-curve+-path+-spline+-%5Bcurve%5D+-%5Bspline%5D+-%5Bbezier-curve%5D+-%5Bbspline%5D+-%5Bnsbezierpath%5D+is%3Aquestion+). Retag those, and the rest can be merged.

Update: merged. We'll just have to deal with the occasional confusion over bezier surfaces or whatever.

Comment: looks like these two tags are still around, with roughly equal use but identical tag descriptions. It'd be nice to still perform a merge and remove either tag - people who have a question about beziers will start writing "bezier" and see two tags with identical description atm, making their choice entirely arbitrary; removing one of the two tags will not lead to confusion. "bezier" has a docs proposal at least pending (if with 0 committed people), "bezier-curve" does not, worth removing the latter?